# error downloading photos with networkImageView

Tags: android, image, download, networkimageview

i am having thsi error that i don't know why is happening and i hope you can help me. I am loading a gridview, that is composed by a couple of networkImageView. I've created a customGridViewAdapter, which i send a List imagesUrls and it downloads this images inside the networkImageViews. well, at this case, the list of url that i am sending has 10 elements. When the adapter load these 10 networkImageView there is no problem, actually it works, but i don't know why, the adapter keeps executing two more times (at this time, it takes the position 0 of the url's list). So, i am having this error

```
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.GridView.setupChild(GridView.java:1373)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:343)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:285)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:418)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1230)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at  android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1873)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11444)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4331)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:11444)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4331)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1666)
11-16 20:07:03.575: E/AndroidRuntime(6142):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1524)
```

this is the part of the adapter that download the images:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  


    String imageUrlSelected = imagesUrl.get(position);

    View vi=convertView;
    RecordHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid_fotos_elemento, null);
        holder = new RecordHolder();

        holder.networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.niv_large);

        if (imagen != null) {
            holder.networkImageView.setImageUrl(imageUrlSelected, imageLoader);
        } else {

        }
    }
    return vi;  
}

public class RecordHolder {

    NetworkImageView networkImageView;
}
```

when i debug step by step i can see that at a point the images load successfully, but, how i said before, it keeps executing.

i would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be too late to help. But usually `Nullpointer Exceptions` with Volley stem from not declaring the custom application class in your manifest. If this step isn't done, then your volley application singleton doesn't initialize because its `onCreate` doesnt get called.

So you should have something like this in your manifest

```
<application 
   android:name="ImgController" <--your volley singleton that extends Application 
   android:allowBackup="true" 
   android:label="@string/app_name">`
```

Comment: Thanks! it is too late as you said but i appreciate your answer anyway!